# Creating a Parse.File Object

Tags: javascript, file-upload, parse-platform

Loving parse at the moment just cant seem to upload a file to parse using the javascript api (client side), the issue is I can't seem to create a parse object. The following is my code:

```
var fileUploadControl = $("#imgInp")[0];
var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
var name = "photo.jpg";
var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);

parseFile.save().then(function() {
// etc
```

The Error I'm getting from the console on chrome is

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at k.$scope.submitReport
(file:///Users/xxx/Documents/projects/script.js:402:27) <- the line which has  var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file); on it
```

Could anybody shed some light on this bizarre situation (I'm fairly certain I'm following the documentation to the letter.

https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#files-classes

Comment: Is `fileUploadControl.files.length > 0`?

Comment: It looks like `Parse` might be `undefined`. Have you required and initialised the Parse SDK?

Comment: I had the length > 0 in there - just took it out for the example and it was definitely there as I console.log-ed it :P And I also triple checked whether I initialised the Parse SDK which seemed to have been fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should try with encoding in base 64, it works finally:

```js
  var fileUploadControl = $("#imgInp")[0];
  var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
  var uploadFile = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        
        var newFile = new Parse.File(String(file.name),{base64:file.image});
        newFile.save();
    
        resolve(newFile)
       
  })
                              
                              
     uploadFile.then(function(){
      
                var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);             
                 //results === your filesUpload
               });
```